# When to create multiple VPCs?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am fairly new to AWS and in the process of rolling out our infrastructure for international clients.

Based on some of the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario3.html) I have read, it looks like to keep things isolated per client, I would need to create a VPC per client. Is this assumption correct? Or should I have a VPC per region and create multiple subnets that isolate each client?

Note - this is mainly to cater for the scenario where I have 2 clients that need to be hosted in the same region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning each client to a single subnet would restrict them to a single availability zone, which wouldn't be very fault tolerant.

At the very least I would split each client into a separate VPC. This will ensure that one client's application can not see network traffic from another client's application. However, to provide further isolation and allow you to properly track the cost of each client's application I would set each up on a separate AWS account, and create a master account with [consolidated billing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/consolidated-billing.html).